# Excel: recognize displayed text set from cell formatting as part of the cell's text

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

How do I make the text that was preset from text formatting to be recognized as part of that cell's own text? Ie. I key in "20" in a cell and preset "packets" as suffix for this cell using the FORMAT CELL function. Therefore that particular cell will display "20 packets" instead of "20".

But when you place your cursor on that cell, the text will still only show "20" and not "20 packets". What shd I do so that that particular cell can be read as "20 packets"? Or for that matter, is there a way to copy this cell to another in such a way that the new cell will be recognized as (not only displayed as) "20 packets"?

Comment: Like `=A1&" packets"`?

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use? 'cell can be read as "20 packets"?' - you can't do that, Excel stores both the number and it's format, but it doesn't merge them. You need to type it manually OR use a formula what converts it for you in another cell OR use macro to convert as you type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have the value *20* in cell **C1**, but have formatted **C1** to display *20 packets*:

[image]

First put the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function txet(rng As Range) As String
    txet = rng.Text
End Function
```

Then in **D1** enter:

```
=txet(C1)
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=txet(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you!!! You made my day!! So the key is to put in the user defined function into my module. :)